# Can F# functions be specialized at runtime?

Tags: reflection, functional-programming, f#

Let's assume I have an F# function that's supposed to run both locally and remotely. I want to create a proxy of the function, and let that proxy decide where to run the function, so the remote call is completely invisible to the outside world. If it's going to run locally, the proxy would just return the function itself, like so:

```
let proxy_local f = f
```

If not, the function must collect all its arguments, then send them over a connection and get the result back. This is where it gets hard: I need to know exactly *which* function the user is hoping to proxy, and also to know the arguments to that function so I can collect them before sending them over the wire.

AFAIK I can't inspect the function argument itself, since at runtime it'll be some unknown subclass of `FSharpFunc` which collects the arguments and invokes the function with them. To work around this, I think I need to use a quotation (BTW, is there a better way to do this part?):

```
let getMethodInfo = function
    | Call (_, mi, _) -> [], mi
    | Lambdas (vs, Call(_, mi, _)) -> List.map (fun (v: Var list) -> (List.head v).Type) vs, mi
    | _ -> failwith "Not a function"

let proxy_remote (f: Expr) =
    let (argTypes, methodInfo) = getMethodInfo f
    … ? // What to return?

let proxy f = if isLocal then proxy_local f else proxy_remote f
```

`getMethodInfo` above won't work for methods with tuple arguments, and we'd need to modify `proxy_local` as well, but let's leave that aside for now. The problem is the return value of `proxy_remote`. It *should* be a function with the same arguments as the original, but it should send them the over the wire at the end. Something like this:

```
let callRemote (method: MethodInfo) a b c … = doHttpConnection()
```

But, the arguments need to be typed. This is the real problem: since F# function calls are translated into FSharpFunc subclasses at *compile time*, there's no way that I know of to get an unspecialized representation that'll work with reflection. My real question is this: can F# functions be specialized at runtime with unknown types?

I can think of two ways to solve this. The first would be to have `proxy` be generic itself:

```
let call1<'p, 'res> (method: MethodInfo) (p: 'p) = method.Invoke(null, [| p :> obj |]) :?> 'res
let call2<'p1, 'p2, 'res> (method: MethodInfo) (p1: 'p1) (p2: 'p2) = method.Invoke(null, [| p1 :> obj; p2 :> obj |]) :?> 'res
…

let proxy1 (f: Expr<'a -> 'b>) (s: string) : 'a -> 'b =
    let (types, mi) = getMethodInfo f
    match types with
    | [_] -> call1<'a, 'b> mi
    | _ -> failwith ""

let proxy2 (f: Expr<'a -> 'b -> 'c>) : 'a -> 'b -> 'c =
    let (types, mi) = getMethodInfo f
    match types with
    | [_; _] -> call2<'a, 'b, 'c> mi
    | _ -> failwith ""
…
```

This would certainly work, but it requires the programmer to think of the number of inputs to each function in advance. Worse, a function with more parameters will work with all proxy methods that accept less arguments:

```
let f a b = a + b
let fproxy = proxy1 f // The result will be of type int -> (int -> int), not what we want at all!
```

The other way is to create special subclasses of FSharpFunc for this purpose:

```
type call1<'a, 'res>(id, ps) =
    inherit FSharpFunc<'a, 'res>()
    override __.Invoke(x: 'a) = callImpl<'res> id ((x :> obj) :: ps)

type call2<'a, 'b, 'res>(id, ps) =
    inherit FSharpFunc<'a, FSharpFunc<'b, 'res>>()
    override __.Invoke(x) = call1<'b, 'res>(id, x :> obj :: ps) :> obj :?> FSharpFunc<'b, 'res>

… 

let proxy (f: Expr<'a -> 'b>) : 'a -> 'b =
    let (types, methodInfo) = getMethodInfo f
    match types with
    | [a] ->
        let t = typedefof<call1<_,_>>.MakeGenericType([| a; methodInfo.ReturnType |])
        t.GetConstructors().[0].Invoke([|methodInfo; []|]) :?> ('a -> 'b)
    | [a; b] ->
        let t = typedefof<call2<_,_,_>>.MakeGenericType([| a; b; methodInfo.ReturnType |])
        t.GetConstructors().[0].Invoke([|methodInfo; []|]) :?> ('a -> 'b)
    … 
    | _ -> failwith ""
```

It'll work, but it probably won't be as performant as what the F# compiler generates, specially with all the dynamic casts. So, again, is there a way to specialize F# functions at runtime, so `typedefof<call1<_,_>>.MakeGenericType([| a; methodInfo.ReturnType |])` can be replaced with a direct call to the function?

Answer (score 1):

After much searching around, it seems there just isn't a way to do what I want. I did learn, however, that other people are also subclassing FSharpFunc for some really odd use cases, so it's not completely unheard of. I'm leaving the question open in case someone has some insight to share.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question. But this is implementation that I played with (hope it can be helpful a little):

```ml
type MyF<'U, 'V>(consumeParam: obj -> obj option, cont: 'V) = 
    inherit FSharpFunc<'U, 'V>()
    override __.Invoke(v: 'U) =
        match consumeParam (v :> obj) with 
        | None -> cont
        | Some result -> result :?> 'V

let netCall (outputT: Type) (paramObjs: obj[]): obj = 
    //tcp http etc
    printfn "%A" paramObjs
    Activator.CreateInstance(outputT)

let proxy (f: 't) : 't = 
    let rec collectTypes (t: Type) (acc: Type list) = 
        if t.Name = "FSharpFunc`2" then 
            let args = t.GetGenericArguments()
            collectTypes args.[1] (args.[0]::acc)
        else t::acc           
    let tps = collectTypes (typeof<'t>) [] //here we collected all types from sugnature to array
    printfn "%A" (tps |> List.map(fun x -> x.Name) |> List.rev) //just for debug
    match tps with 
    | [] -> failwithf "Could not be here" //signature cannot be empty
    | [ _ ] -> f //provided param is not a function
    | outputT::inputT::otherT -> //take last two types: ... -> inputT -> outputT
        let mutable paramIndex = 0 //at each call of FSharpFunc we add param to array
        let paramsHolder: obj[] = Array.zeroCreate (otherT.Length + 1)     
        let consumeParam (paramValue: obj) = 
            paramsHolder.[paramIndex] <- paramValue
            paramIndex <- paramIndex + 1
            if paramIndex = paramsHolder.Length then //if all params given
                Some(netCall outputT paramsHolder)//network call 
            else None
        let initialFunc = //build initial func inputT -> outputT
            typedefof<MyF<_,_>>.MakeGenericType([| inputT; outputT |])
                .GetConstructors().[0].Invoke([| consumeParam :> obj; Activator.CreateInstance(outputT) |])
        let rec buildF (func: obj) otherT = //recursivelly build other funcs
            match otherT with 
            | [] -> func 
            | inputT::otherT -> 
                let newFunc = 
                    typedefof<MyF<_,_>>.MakeGenericType([| inputT; func.GetType().BaseType |])
                        .GetConstructors().[0].Invoke([| consumeParam :> obj; func |])
                buildF newFunc otherT
        let finalFunc = buildF initialFunc otherT
        finalFunc :?> 't  //final cast

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    let myTestF1 a b = a + b
    let myTestF1Proxied = proxy myTestF1
    printfn "myTestF1Proxied created"
    let res = myTestF1Proxied 1 2
    let myTestF2 a b c d e = 1.0 + a + b * c - d + (float) e
    let myTestF2Proxied = proxy myTestF2
    printfn "myTestF2Proxied created"
    let res = myTestF2Proxied 1. 2. 3. 4. 5
    // let myTestF3 a b c = a::b::c
    // let myTestF3Proxied = proxy myTestF3
    // printfn "myTestF3Proxied created"
    // let res = myTestF3Proxied "test" "a" []
    printfn "Done"
    0
```

Output for first two tests:

```
["Int32"; "Int32"; "Int32"]
myTestF1Proxied created
[|1; 2|]
["Double"; "Double"; "Double"; "Double"; "Int32"; "Double"]
myTestF2Proxied created
[|1.0; 2.0; 3.0; 4.0; 5|]
```

Third test crashes on Activator.CreateInstance. It is interesting case because function that is proxied here is `let myTestF3 a b c = a::b::c`. It is generic: 'a -> 'a -> 'a list. Therefore, this is the quesion how to proxy such functions (assume we can constraint proxy with nullable types or use Option<'a> somehow).

**UPDATE**

Here is improved code:

1) Activator.CreateInstance is removed - it was not able to create FSharpList at runtime

2) invokeFunc - which is a stub for netCall - but can be used on other remote side. Function applies parameters to generic func recursivelly

3) MyF is splitted to two classes: MyF and MyFInit - this allows to remove Activator.CreateInstance on initial call

Now third test succeed. Code:

```ml
type MyF<'U, 'V>(consumeParam, cont: 'V) = 
    inherit FSharpFunc<'U, 'V>()
    override __.Invoke(v: 'U) = consumeParam (v :> obj); cont

type MyFInit<'U, 'V>(consumeParam: obj -> obj) = 
    inherit FSharpFunc<'U, 'V>()
    override __.Invoke(v: 'U) = consumeParam (v :> obj) :?> 'V

let invokeFunc f (outputT: Type) (paramObjs: obj[]) = 
    let rec invoke partiallyAppliedFunc givenParams = 
        match givenParams with
        | p::otherParams ->
            let methodInfo = partiallyAppliedFunc.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke", [| p.GetType() |])
            if isNull methodInfo then 
                partiallyAppliedFunc //fully applied ?
            else 
                let newFunc = methodInfo.Invoke(partiallyAppliedFunc, [| p |])
                invoke newFunc otherParams
        | _ -> 
            partiallyAppliedFunc //params are empty 
    invoke f (paramObjs |> Array.toList)

let netCall f (outputT: Type) (paramObjs: obj[]): obj = 
    //tcp http etc instead of invokeFunc
    printfn "%A" paramObjs
    let res = invokeFunc f outputT paramObjs
    printfn "Res: %A" res
    res

let proxy (f: 't) : 't = 
    let rec collectTypes (t: Type) (acc: Type list) = 
        if t.Name = "FSharpFunc`2" then 
            let args = t.GetGenericArguments()
            collectTypes args.[1] (args.[0]::acc)
        else t::acc           
    let tps = collectTypes (typeof<'t>) [] //here we collected all types from sugnature to array
    printfn "%A" (tps |> List.map(fun x -> x.Name) |> List.rev) //just for debug
    match tps with 
    | [] -> failwithf "Could not be here" //signature cannot be empty
    | [ _ ] -> f //provided param is not a function
    | outputT::inputT::otherT -> //take last two types: ... -> inputT -> outputT
        let mutable paramIndex = 0 //at each call of FSharpFunc we add param to array
        let paramsHolder: obj[] = Array.zeroCreate (otherT.Length + 1)   
        let consumeParamInit (paramValue: obj) = 
            paramsHolder.[paramIndex] <- paramValue
            paramIndex <- paramIndex + 1
            netCall f outputT paramsHolder//network call 
        let consumeParam (paramValue: obj) = 
            paramsHolder.[paramIndex] <- paramValue
            paramIndex <- paramIndex + 1
        let initialFunc = //build initial func inputT -> outputT
            typedefof<MyFInit<_,_>>.MakeGenericType([| inputT; outputT |])
                .GetConstructors().[0].Invoke([| consumeParamInit :> obj |])
        let rec buildF (func: obj) otherT = //recursivelly build other funcs
            match otherT with 
            | [] -> func 
            | inputT::otherT -> 
                let newFunc = 
                    typedefof<MyF<_,_>>.MakeGenericType([| inputT; func.GetType().BaseType |])
                        .GetConstructors().[0].Invoke([| consumeParam :> obj; func |])
                buildF newFunc otherT
        let finalFunc = buildF initialFunc otherT
        finalFunc :?> 't  //final cast

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 
    let myTestF1 a b = a + b
    let myTestF1Proxied = proxy myTestF1
    printfn "myTestF1Proxied created"
    let res = myTestF1Proxied 1 2
    let myTestF2 a b c d e = 1.0 + a + b * c - d + (float) e
    let myTestF2Proxied = proxy myTestF2
    printfn "myTestF2Proxied created"
    let res = myTestF2Proxied 1. 2. 3. 4. 5
    let myTestF3 a b c = a::b.ToString()::c
    let myTestF3Proxied = proxy myTestF3
    printfn "myTestF3Proxied created"
    let res = myTestF3Proxied "test" 1 []
    printfn "Done"
    0
```

Output:

```
["Int32"; "Int32"; "Int32"]
myTestF1Proxied created
[|1; 2|]
Res: 3
["Double"; "Double"; "Double"; "Double"; "Int32"; "Double"]
myTestF2Proxied created
[|1.0; 2.0; 3.0; 4.0; 5|]
Res: 9.0
["String"; "Int32"; "FSharpList`1"; "FSharpList`1"]
myTestF3Proxied created
[|"test"; 1; []|]
Res: ["test"; "1"]
Done
```

Comment: I think the reason why your third test crashes is that you're assuming all input to the function to be of the same type, so when you get a different input (the list in the last parameter) your code crashes.

Comment: @Arshia001 - I posted an update above. No, it is not a case: the output parameters could be of different types (see the output). Even though provided code works, it is usefull to provide some decoration to function invocation locally. But to call function remotelly (I mean the same function), initial function code should exist on remote side before we send a request.

Comment: Of course, we're assuming the same libraries are uploaded everywhere the code runs.